# hibernate не видит обновленные данные в таблице

Tags: java, hibernate

Здравствуйте.  Я пишу программу на java с использованием Hibernate. нижеприведенный код, должен обращается 1 раз в несколько секунд к таблице, чтобы проверить, не появились ли там новые данные с колонкой state = 0.

```
class Dao {
    public List<MyTable> getNewRows() throws Exception {
        Session session = null;
        List<MyTable> result;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            result = session.createQuery("from MyTable where state = 0 ").list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Работать должно так: я выставляю некоторым строкам в таблице сторонней программой  state = 0 и метод должен их подхватить, ведь он вызывается в цикле, с задержкой в 3 секунды.
Но метод подхватывает только те строки , которым был выставлен статус 0 **до** запуска программы, если же выставлять статусы **во время** работы программы, то метод больше ничего не "цепляет", то есть он не видит, что появились новые  строки со статусом 0.

Я попробовал вместо Session использовать StatelessSession, и пробовал после HQL запроса дописывать  session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE), но не помогло.

вот util

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        // loads configuration and mappings
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        // builds a session factory from the service registry
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
    return sessionFactory;

}
```

}

вот cfg

```
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">login</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
```

Кроме этих строк в cfg Ничего больше нет.

Помогите разобраться почему так происходит.

Comment: Покажите как выглядит цикл, который это делает? Возможно вы все делаете в одной транзакции для бд. Включите логгирование hql в лог, покажите что там выходит.

Comment: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.firmname.hibernate.entities.MyTable; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5930977514948150750, local class serialVersionUID = 6205997936559234017

вот что пишет  логгер

Comment: извиняюсь, то старая запись, 4-ех часовой давности. А нового ничего нет, лог молчит.

Comment: в настройках hibernate есть такая функция hibernate.show_sql = false, поставьте ее в true, посмотрите падают ли в лог функции подбора. Заходит ли вообще в цикл раз в 3 секунды?

Comment: Посмотрите в sessionFactory возможно ли использовать getCurrentSession? sessionFactory самостоятельно отвечает за управлением сессиями.

Comment: Подключитесь к БД какой-нибудь утилитой/визуалайзером и выполните выборку данных параллельно вашему циклу. Если утилита "видит" записи, значит проблема с циклом, если не "видит", значит проблема со "сторонней программой". Если "сторонняя программа" и есть утилита, попробуйте её закрыть, т.к. если она не завершает транзакции автоматически, то либо откат произойдёт и новые записи потеряются, либо коммит и тогда цикл таки "увидит" записи

Comment: 1. сделал show_sql=true, видно как раз 3 секунды постоянно повторяется запрос.
2. Попробовал использовать getCurrentSession вместо openSession, разницы не увидел.
3.  Сторонняя утилита (в моем случае программа heidisql) , видит все изменения которые делает hibernate.  А hibernate не видит никаких изменений которые делает heidisql, даже если поменять значения строк а потом оболочку перезапустить.

Comment: CurrentSession как я понял закрывается, когда я делаю commit.  Но до тех пор она висит открытая.  Но commit я делаю только, когда что-то записываю, если же просто хочу что-то выбрать из базы, то commit я не делаю.  Это правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался со своей проблемой.
Если кратко, то помогла замена метода openSession() на getCurrentSession() и  commit в конце запроса.

А  вот так если все целиком :

В  hibernate.cfg.xml  добавляем такую строчку.

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

А Dao теперь выглядит так

```
     class Dao {
        public List<MyTable> getNewRows() throws Exception {                      
           Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
           session.getTransaction().begin();
           List<MyTable> result = session.createQuery("from MyTable where state = 0 ").list();
           session.getTransaction().commit();       
           return result;
        }
    }
```